# Von Neumann Analysis on Gauss Seidel?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to apply [Von Neumann](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) Analysis to Gauss Seidel, that is. Given the per row formula:

$$x^{m+1} = \frac{1}{A_{jj}}(b_j - A_{j,j-1}x^{m+1}_{j-1} - A_{j,j+1}x_{j+1}^m) 
  \label{GsS}$$

Where $A= D_2 + I$ and $D$ is the finite difference matrix approximation of the derivative coefficients.

I am trying to find the smoothing rate for it. I tried doing Von Nuemann analysis as someone suggested to me, this got me here:

We have the GS formula:

$$x^{m+1} = \frac{1}{A_{jj}}(b_j - A_{j,j-1}x^{m+1}_{j-1} - A_{j,j+1}x_{j+1}^m) 
 \label{GS}$$

If we mimic the Von Neumann stability analysis from a resource such as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis.

We get the following terms for the error:

\begin{multline}
 \\ 
\epsilon^{m+1}_j = E(t + \Delta t)e^{ikx}\\
\epsilon^{m}_{j+1} = E(t)e^{ik(x+\Delta x)}\\
\epsilon^{m}_{j-1} = E(t)e^{ik(x-\Delta x)}\\
\epsilon^{m+1}_{j-1} = E(t + \Delta t)e^{ik(x - \Delta x)}\\
\\
\end{multline}

Since the error obeys the same LFS differential equation as the solution, when the RHS function is replaced by the residual, we can substitute the expressions from the above :

$$E(t + \Delta t)e^{ik_mx} = \frac{1}{A_{jj}}(b_j - A_{j,j-1}E(t + \Delta t)e^{ik(x - \Delta x)} - A_{j,j+1}E(t)e^{ik(x+\Delta x)})$$

So:

$$E(t + \Delta t)e^{ik_mx} + \frac{A_{j,j-1}}{A_{jj}}E(t + \Delta t)e^{ik(x - \Delta x)} = \frac{1}{A_{jj}}(b_j - A_{j,j+1}E(t)e^{ik(x+\Delta x)})$$

Then:

$$E(t + \Delta t)\bigg(e^{ik_mx} + \frac{A_{j,j-1}}{A_{jj}}e^{ik(x - \Delta x)}\bigg) = \frac{1}{A_{jj}}(b_j - A_{j,j+1}E(t)e^{ik(x+\Delta x)})$$

Now I am utterly stuck. I can't express the LHS as a ratio of $E(t) E(t+ \Delta t)$ without any of those 2 showing up on the RHS.

What do I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. When I replaced my terms I left the $b_j$ term in, however the error is defined as the difference between iterations, so the $b_j$ cancels out i.e. just delete the $b_j$ term from my last expression and it all works out.